# Alternative for Downloading Several Images to a Web Page

Tags: image, xhtml, prefetch

We all know that pre-fetching images can run slow because of browser limits in the HTTP protocol, right? So, I have **XHTML, jQuery, Apache httpd, and PHP** at my disposal. What's an easy solution to pre-fetch a lot of images, without using sprites or multiple hosts?

See, I have these themes one selects with a SELECT box. It changes the 200x200 theme image on the right of the box. Unfortunately there are like 150 of these. So, when I load the page, the progress bar keeps running to download these all.

How can I get these images pre-fetching faster without using sprites or multiple hosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hindsight is probably 20/20. I probably should have implemented it in sprites, as well as for many of the buttons I used on the site. It's just that I lack a good sprite editor tool that speeds that process up.

Anyway, the strategy I went with was to use [Javascript prefetch via jQuery](http://www.4thkingdom.com/public/computers/789073-web-site-speed-prefetching-images-css/view-post.html). But even that wasn't enough. I had to wrap that function in a setTimeout(), but that only helped a little. I then had to fire that setTimeout() during a login form submit. It made the login form submit slightly longer, but made the website appear snappy on load.

Answer (score 3):

If it's just a theme change, which probably rarely happens (right)? Then why wouldn't you just load the image for a theme when the the `select` is changed and a new theme is chosen? It seems "strange" to load 150 images of which 149 may not be seen.

Correct me if I'm missing the point - and if so, can you provide a screenshot so I can get an idea of what you're really trying to show?

Comment: The problem with that strategy is that the user selects from the select and needs to see what the new theme would like with each select, and to make an evaluation, and then go with that selection. He can't just click the select and click View (where I would pull over AJAX) because that would diminish the quality user experience I need.

Comment: But it's a 200x200 image, right? That should take almost no time to download on a "normal" connection. Is the fix easy enough to just show a "loading" indicator for a second while the image loads?

Comment: That still might be too slow for the UX. I'll try something like an AJAX prefetch here and see if that will help: http://www.4thkingdom.com/public/computers/789073-web-site-speed-prefetching-images-css/view-post.html

Comment: Okay, don't forget that UX can also be negatively affected by downloading 150 never-seen images. Is this on a page that is specific for theme selection (a change-theme page) or is it on every page?

Comment: I came up with a strategy. I used Javascript prefetch, from that 4thkingdom link, but did it during the login process, and via setTimeout(). This made it appear to load super fast.